# How to generate/retrieve token from Cybersource Secure Acceptance API?

Tags: rest, integration, cybersource

I have attempted to use the provided test data from the Cybersource documentation to create a token for a test PAN. However, when attempting to do so (assuming it was a REST Api) it results in a "403 - Forbidden" error. The documentation is limited, as it doesn't give much information on the API other than the following:

```
(Test) Endpoint: https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/silent/token/create
```

Request to create a standalone payment token:

```
reference_number=123456789
transaction_type=create_payment_token
currency=usd
amount=100.00
locale=en
access_key=e2b0c0d0e0f0g0h0i0j0k0l0m0n0o0p3
profile_id=0FFEAFFB-8171-4F34-A22D-1CD38A28A384
transaction_uuid=02815b4f08e56882751a043839b7b481
signed_date_time=2013-07-11T15:16:54Z
signed_field_names=comma separated list of signed fields
unsigned_field_names=comma separated list of unsigned fields
signature=WrXOhTzhBjYMZROwiCug2My3jiZHOqATimcz5EBA07M=
payment_method=card
card_type=001
card_number=4111111111111111
card_expiry_date=12-2022
card_cvn=005
bill_to_forename=Joe
bill_to_surname=Smith
bill_to_email=joesmith@example.com
bill_to_address_line1=1 My Apartment
bill_to_address_city=Mountain View
bill_to_address_postal_code=94043
bill_to_address_state=CA
bill_to_address_country=US
```

Is this a REST or SOAP API? How can this be tested in Postman? I tested to check if either works, and was unsuccessful. There is no information on what to include in the header either, so this is a bit puzzling.

Example POST test I am attempting:

```
POST https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/silent/token/create
Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json

{
reference_number:123456789
transaction_type:create_payment_token
currency:usd
amount:100.00
locale:en
access_key:e2b0c0d0e0f0g0h0i0j0k0l0m0n0o0p3
profile_id:0FFEAFFB-8171-4F34-A22D-1CD38A28A384
transaction_uuid:02815b4f08e56882751a043839b7b481
signed_date_time:2019-03-07T06:16:54Z
signed_field_names:profile_id,access_key,transaction_uuid,signed_field_names,unsigned_field_names,signed_date_time,locale,transaction_type,reference_number,auth_trans_ref_no,amount,currency,card_type,card_number,card_expiry_date,card_cvn,payment_method,bill_to_forename,bill_to_surname,bill_to_email,bill_to_address_line1,bill_to_address_city,bill_to_address_postal_code,bill_to_address_state,bill_to_address_country
unsigned_field_names:
signature:WrXOhTzhBjYMZROwiCug2My3jiZHOqATimcz5EBA07M=
payment_method:card
card_type:001
card_number:4111111111111111
card_expiry_date:12-2022
card_cvn:005
bill_to_forename:Joe
bill_to_surname:Smith
bill_to_email:joesmith@example.com
bill_to_address_line1:1 My Apartment
bill_to_address_city:Mountain View
bill_to_address_postal_code:94043
bill_to_address_state:CA
bill_to_address_country:US
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is this a REST or SOAP API?"
The URL, https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/silent/token/create, is used for Secure Acceptance Checkout API. Secure Acceptance Checkout API is neither a SOAP API or a REST API. It is designed to be used as an HTML form POST from a customers browser.

If your goal is to use a REST API from the browser then you will want to use Secure Acceptance Flexible Token documented [here](https://www.cybersource.com/developers/integration_methods/secure-acceptance-flexible-token/).

If your goal is to use Secure Acceptance Checkout API the full documentation for that is [here](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_Checkout_API/Secure_Acceptance_Checkout_API.pdf).

"How can this be tested in Postman?"
Since this is not meant to be a REST API call but an HTML form POST and HTML response you may have limited success with Postman. For example even if you get the request to work successfully the response will be an HTML document not JSON.

One problem I see is that you are using the example signature, and that will not work for you. Ensure that you follow the documentation on how to create your signature as well as set the signed and unsigned fields.

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, is there a way to utilize a secure acceptance tokenization page that is hosted by CyberSource that can be redirected to from a source platform?

Comment: Yes, I think you want Secure Acceptance **Hosted** Checkout API documented [here](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_Hosted_Checkout/Secure_Acceptance_Hosted_Checkout.pdf). See page 51 for all the endpoints. If you only want to create a token then the test endpoint is https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/token/create

Comment: When attempting tokenization with the test endpoint, I am encountering the following error: 'A system error has been encountered. This field is invalid or missing.Please contact Customer Support.: ots_profileid'. Do you have any insight on how to resolve this?

Comment: You will need to contact CyberSource support and ask them to enable tokenization on your test account. It is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

@J.J. - the error you encountered -- "*This field is invalid or missing.Please contact Customer Support.: ots_profileid'* ". Is telling you that you are missing (or have an invalid) profileID in your request payload. The system doesn't know what profile to use when processing this request.